# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition) not working in jquery mobile page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i am trying to get user's current location in my jquery mobile webapp..i used code given on w3schools.com http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

This code is working fine on w3schools but when i include it in my jquery mobile page, then it does not works..i uploaded app on my server and tested on my phone and laptop..the code didnt work..

my jquery mobile page code: http://pastebin.com/qZafsJt4

Comment: Try updating your jQuery version. I tested your code out with jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.0b1 and it worked just fine. You can take a look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewlively/f8MqW/).

Comment: oops..i was using jquery 1.6.4 ..thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your version on jQuery to 1.9.1